# Restructure this Java code to allow for sometime have 4 items in packagePriceList

Tags: java

Please help me restructure this Java code to allow for sometime have 4 items in packagePriceList.

```
public static HTMLSelectOptionsElement listPremiumPackageTermsWithPrice(String[] packagePriceList, int cyberSourceBillingMode) {
    HTMLSelectOptionsElement optionsElement = new HTMLSelectOptionsElement();

    // Testing only. Allows for a shorter recurring term for QA testing.
    if (cyberSourceBillingMode == DiceUtilConstants.CYBERSOURCE_BILLING_MODE_ICS_WEEKLY_OVERRIDE) {
        optionsElement.addOption("1 Week", String.valueOf(UserPackage.PREMIUM_PACKAGE_TERM_7_DAYS));
    }
    optionsElement.addOption("1 Month - " + packagePriceList[0], String.valueOf(UserPackage.PREMIUM_PACKAGE_TERM_30_DAYS));
    optionsElement.addOption("3 Months - " + packagePriceList[1], String.valueOf(UserPackage.PREMIUM_PACKAGE_TERM_90_DAYS));
    optionsElement.addOption("6 Months - " + packagePriceList[2], String.valueOf(UserPackage.PREMIUM_PACKAGE_TERM_180_DAYS));
    optionsElement.addOption("12 Months - " + packagePriceList[3], String.valueOf(UserPackage.PREMIUM_PACKAGE_TERM_365_DAYS));

    return optionsElement;
}
```

I thought about just catching the IndexOutOfBoundsException but would that be a bit of a hack?

Comment: The question is not clear: you'll always get `packagePriceList` of length 4, or sometimes less, sometimes more?

Comment: Also thought about adding a completely new method or adding a check in the method on the size of packagePriceList.

Comment: Yes toto2 the packagePriceList sometimes has 3 and sometimes 4.  I apologize for the question not being clear.

Answer (score 1):

First, a simple solution:

```
optionsElement.addOption("1 Month - " + packagePriceList[0], String.valueOf(UserPackage.PREMIUM_PACKAGE_TERM_30_DAYS));
optionsElement.addOption("3 Months - " + packagePriceList[1], String.valueOf(UserPackage.PREMIUM_PACKAGE_TERM_90_DAYS));
optionsElement.addOption("6 Months - " + packagePriceList[2], String.valueOf(UserPackage.PREMIUM_PACKAGE_TERM_180_DAYS));
if (packagePriceList.length == 4)
   optionsElement.addOption("12 Months - " + packagePriceList[3], String.valueOf(UserPackage.PREMIUM_PACKAGE_TERM_365_DAYS));
```

But I don't like the signature of `listPremiumPackageTermsWithPrice(String[] packagePriceList,...)`.  The problem is that you must implicitly know that the the first element corresponds to 1 month, etc.  It would be better to have an argument which is of type `Map<PackageTerm, String>`, where the key of the map is one of `UserPackage.PREMIUM_PACKAGE_TERM_XX_DAYS` and the value of the map is the same string as before.  If your `UserPackage.PREMIUM_PACKAGE_TERM_XX_DAYS` where actually `enum`'s, you could use an `EnumMap`.

Here is the enum I would define:

```
public enum PackageTerm {
  PREMIUM_PACKAGE_TERM_30_DAYS("1 month"), 
  PREMIUM_PACKAGE_TERM_90_DAYS("3 months"), 
  PREMIUM_PACKAGE_TERM_180_DAYS("6 months"), 
  PREMIUM_PACKAGE_TERM_365_DAYS("12 months");

  private String timePeriodString;

  private PackageTerm(String timePeriodString) {
     this.timePeriodString = timePeriodString);
  }

  public String printedString(String price) {
    return timePeriodString + " - " + price;
  }
}
```

and the method is changed to:

```
HTMLSelectOptionsElement listPremiumPackageTermsWithPrice(Map<PackageTerm, String> packagesWithPrice, ...) {
   for (PackageTerm packageTerm : PackageTerm.values()) { // in the order 1/3/6/12 months
      String priceIfAny = packagesWithPrice.get(packageTerm); // null if not present
      if (priceIfAny != null)
         optionsElement.addOptions(packageTerm.printedString(priceIfAny), packageTerm.toString());
         // You would need to override PackageTerm.toString().  By default it is the name of the enum.
   }
}
```

Note that you could put other relevant data and methods within the enum PackageTerm.

Comment: Not coherent number of days PREMIUM_PACKAGE_TERM_30_DAYS("6 months"), PREMIUM_PACKAGE_TERM_30_DAYS("12 months");